# lvalue required as left operand of assignment (bool matrix)

Tags: c++

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef vector< vector<bool> > Tauler;

void baixell(Tauler& t, char fila, int colu, int tamany, char posi) {
     cin >> fila >> colu >> tamany >> posi;
     int fila2 = 1;
     while (fila != 'a') {
      ++fila2;
      fila = fila - ('b' - 'a');
     }
     int k;
     if (posi == 'h') {
      k = fila2 - 1;
      for (int j = colu - 1; j < tamany + (colu - 1); ++j) {
           t[k][j] = true;
      }
     }
     else if (posi = 'v') {
      k = colu - 1;
      for (int j = fila2 - 1; j < tamany + (fila2 - 1); ++j) {
           t[j][k] = true;
      }
     }

}

void distancia(const Tauler& t, int& i, int& j) {
    int dist = 1;
    bool trobat = false;
    while (not trobat) {
        if (i + dist <= 9 and not trobat) {
         if (t[i + dist][j]) trobat = true;
    }
        if (j + dist <= 9 and not trobat) {
         if (t[i][j + dist]) trobat = true;
    }
        if (i - dist >= 0 and not trobat) {
         if (t[i - dist][j]) trobat = true;
    }
        if (j - dist >= 0 and not trobat) {
         if (t[i][j - dist]) trobat = true;
    }
        if (i + dist <= 9 and j + dist <= 9 and not trobat) {
         if (t[i + dist][j + dist]) trobat = true;
    }
        if (i - dist >= 0 and j - dist >= 0 and not trobat) {
         if (t[i - dist][j - dist]) trobat = true;
    }
        if (i + dist <= 9 and j - dist >= 0 and not trobat) {
         if (t[i + dist][j - dist]) trobat = true;
    }
        if (i - dist >= 0 and j + dist <= 9 and not trobat) {
         if (t[i - dist][j + dist]) trobat = true;
    }
        if (not trobat) ++dist;
    }
    cout << " vaixell mes proper a distancia " << dist << endl;
}

void disparap2(const Tauler& t) {
    char coordi;
    int coordj,numcordi;
    while (cin >> coordi) {
        cin >> coordj;
    --coordj;
        numcordi = coordi - 'a';
        if (t[numcordi][coordj]) {
        t[numcordi][coordj] = false;
            cout << coordi << coordj + 1 << " tocat!" << endl;
    }
        else {
            cout << coordi << coordj + 1 << " aigua!";
            distancia(t,numcordi,coordj);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
     Tauler t(10,vector<bool>(10,false));
     char fila, posi;
     int colu, tamany;
     for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
      baixell(t,fila,colu,tamany,posi);
     }
     cout << "  12345678910" << endl;
     char files = 'a';
     for (int files2 = 0; files2 < 10; ++files2) {
      cout << files << " ";
      for (int columnes = 0; columnes < 10; ++columnes) {
           if (t[files2][columnes]) cout << "X";
           else cout << ".";
      }
      cout << endl;
      files = files + ('b' - 'a');
     }
     cout << endl;
     disparap2(t);

}
```

On this "if" condition on the third void:

```
if (t[numcordi][coordj]) {
        cout << coordi << coordj + 1 << " tocat!" << endl;
    t[numcordi][coordj] = false;
}
```

the compiler says lvalue required as left operand of assignmente here:

```
t[numcordi][coordj] = false;
```

I just want to assign a false value on that position of the matrix. Why here is an error?

Comment: What is the type of your "matrix"?

Comment: vector< vector<bool> >

Comment: This would work. Either it `t` isn't actually of type `vector<vector<bool>>`, or there's something else you aren't showing us.

Comment: Please, you should post whole code, so we can halp you.

Comment: Is t const or a const pointer?

Comment: We need to see as you initialize the vector (how to add elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared t as a const reference of type Tauler in your disparap2 function. So if you index it, you get a `const vector<bool>`. If you index that one, you get a const reference, to which you cannot assign.

Comment: Aaaaah OK, so I just have to declare t as Tauler, not const. Thank you!